# Year over Year growth of survey satisfaction with DAX power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the data warehouse design as follows:

[image]

**Explanation:**

The data warehouse contains 4 tables, 3 dimensions (DATE, QUESTION_ANSWER, SURVEY_RESPONDENT) they are linked to each other using surrogate keys. and the data is the result of a survey questions.

The RESPONDENT has a set of questions, and the possible answers are from 1 to 5 (bad to great).

My question is related to the DIM_QUESTION_ANSWER table, I need to analyse the satisfaction of the RESPONDENTS on a survey.

The satisfaction is the (number of RESPONDENTS with an average response equal to or greater than four "4") divided by (the number of all the RESPONDENTS).

I calculated the survey satisfaction percentage using the DAX formula below:

```
AVRSCOREALLCOUNT = 
VAR MTABLE = SUMMARIZE(FACT_SURVEY_RESPONSES,FACT_SURVEY_RESPONSES[RESPONDENT_SRGT])
VAR AVGTABLE = ADDCOLUMNS(MTABLE,"AVR",CALCULATE(AVERAGE(DIM_QUESTION_ANSWER[ANSWER_VALUE])))
VAR FILTERED = FILTER(AVGTABLE,[AVR]>= 4)

RETURN 
IF(
    NOT ISBLANK(COUNTROWS(AVGTABLE)),
    DIVIDE(COUNTROWS(FILTERED),COUNTROWS(AVGTABLE))
    
)
```

**What I want to calculate and what I achieve:**

I want to calculate the Year over Year of the satisfaction; so I tried to calculate the last year satisfaction using SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR with this formula:

```
AVRSCOREALLCOUNT-LASTYEAR = 
VAR MTABLE = SUMMARIZE(FACT_SURVEY_RESPONSES,FACT_SURVEY_RESPONSES[RESPONDENT_SRGT])
VAR AVGTABLE = ADDCOLUMNS(MTABLE,"AVR",CALCULATE(AVERAGE(DIM_QUESTION_ANSWER[ANSWER_VALUE]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DIM_DATE[Date])))
VAR FILTERED = FILTER(AVGTABLE,[AVR]>=4)

VAR AVRSCORELASTYEAR = DIVIDE(COUNTROWS(FILTERED),COUNTROWS(AVGTABLE))

RETURN AVRSCORELASTYEAR
```

**The problem:**

The result of last year's formula is wrong, it's just returning the result of the current year satisfaction, I don't know where the mistake is, is it because I am using the date from the DIM_DATE and its not a direct column in the DIM_QUESTION_ANSWER table?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace MTABLE and AVGTABLE as below?

```
VAR AVGTABLE =
CALCULATETABLE (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( FACT_SURVEY_RESPONSES, FACT_SURVEY_RESPONSES[RESPONDENT_SRGT] ),
        "AVR", CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( DIM_QUESTION_ANSWER[ANSWER_VALUE] ) )
    ),
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( DIM_DATE[Date] )
)
```

EDIT: Or better yet, if the original measure works, why not simply try

```
AVRSCOREALLCOUNT-LASTYEAR =
CALCULATE ( AVRSCOREALLCOUNT, SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( DimDate[Date] ) )
```

Comment: it still gives this year value, I think the problem is with date passed, instead of passing the date from DIM_DATE I should pass the surrogate key of the date from the fact table, but the SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR didn't accept it as its not in a date format